# Sproutcore custom getter/setter

Tags: sproutcore

In Sproutcore i am using the universal setter/getter method like so:

```
foo.set('bar', newValue );
val = foo.get('bar');
```

This is quite different to Objective-c, how would i write a custom getter/ setter?

### EDIT

Thanks to those who helped, the way to do it is

```
bar: function( propKey, propVal ) {
  if(propVal===undefined) {   // called as getter method
    var computedBarValue = ...
    return computedBarValue;
  } else {
    this.bar = propVal + ...    // called as setter method
  }
}.property()
```

As you can see, you have one method that is the both the getter and the setter.

if you call

```
val = foo.get('bar');
```

the method argument 'propVal' will be undefined.

if you call

```
foo.set('bar', newValue );
```

the method argument 'propVal' will be newValue

Answer (score 2):

Custom setter/getter function would look smth like this:

```
bar: function(key, value){
  if(value != undefined){
    this._bar = value;
  }

  return this._bar;
}
```

This would simply get/set the value. To do smth on set, just add what you want after this._bar = value, to do smth on get, just add if value == undefined.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer - this is pretty much what i think won't work.. but ill try to do some tests and maybe expand the question with some more details.

Comment: The ToDos demo described at http://guides.sproutcore.com/html_based.html includes this setter/getter pattern for the allAreDone function